# How to split 8GB WAVE files (24h lasting) into smaller files (1h lasting) in R?

Tags: r, audio, wav

I would like to split 8 GB (24h lasting) WAVE files into smaller WAVE files (1-hour lasting). I have about 800 large files to split, so I couldn't do this manually.

I try using packages: tuneR, seewave and phonTools. Below is fragment of my script in R:

```
example1=readWave("example.wav", from=0, to=1, units= "hours")
savewav(example1,f=48000)

example2=readWave("example.wav", from=22, to=23, units= "hours")
savewav(example2,f=48000)
```

When I ran example 1 everything was correct. I received one-hour lasting WAVE file.
Problem is with spliting later hours of 8 GB files, like in example2. I get comment in console: readBin(con, int, n = N, size = bytes, signed = (bytes != 1), ': invalid 'n' argument.

Probably R has a problem with the size of this file, which is too large because WAVE are limited to 4GB. I am certain that this file includes all 24 hours recording because I change the file from WAVE to FLACK in audio software Audacity and all data was there.

There is any other solution to spiting such a large file in R?

Answer (score 2):

Use ffmpeg:

```
ffmpeg -i example.wav -f segment -segment_time 3600 -c copy out%03d.wav
```

Reference: https://www.ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-formats.html#segment_002c-stream_005fsegment_002c-ssegment

Comment: I think this would be the way to go as well. `ffmpeg` is much better suited to this kind of task. If the OP wants to use it from within R, they can always use `system()`. They could also use `sox` like this: `sox example.wav out.wav trim 0 3600 : newfile : restart`. +1

Comment: Thank you. When I used your code, the program created only 12 files (below 4GB). But when I add extra information to the code, everything was correct. I use following code: `D:\Desktop\ffmpeg\bin>ffmpeg -f s16le -ar 48000 -i example.wav -f segment -segment_time 3600 -c copy out%03d.wav`.